# Why doesn't the USA try to impose changes in Mexico to stop illegal immigration?

Tags: united-states, immigration, illegal-immigration, mexico

Building a wall doesn't seem very intelligent in my opinion.

There will be illegal immigrants as long as poor Mexicans have less opportunities in Mexico. And I'm pretty sure Americans know that. So why haven't the almighty USA been trying to impose changes in Mexico or working together with Mexico to really solve the roots of the problem?

Comment: "Keep having children carelessly" is a hopelessly simplistic view of the nature of the problems Mexico has. Also, many people crossing the Mexico-USA border aren't even Mexicans and many people staying illegally in rich countries actually entered legally...

Comment: "In 2013, Mexican-born immigrants accounted for approximately 28 percent of the 41.3 million foreign born in the United States, making them by far the largest immigrant group in the country." [link](http://www.migrationpolicy.org/article/frequently-requested-statistics-immigrants-and-immigration-united-states)

Comment: Of course but 28% is even less than I thought! It means that non-Mexicans are not only a significant factor but in fact a large majority of immigrants. And we are talking about people currently living in the US, not current flows/recent arrivals or illegal immigrants specifically. You need to pay attention to all these distinctions if you want to approach the problem intelligently.

Comment: Indeed I oversimplified the problem because I actually didn't want to discuss every possible problem that accounts for illegal immigration. I still think I did a pretty good resume though. I was more interested in knowing why the US doesn't work more actively with Mexico and in Mexico to solve the problem.

Comment: And the answer to that question is “because the problem is much more complicated than that”. My point is precisely that the notion that Mexicans have too many children is not a good summary, it's simplistic to the point of hindering understanding. Also, a very important point on the same note: Mexico's birth rate is not particularly high and its fertility rate is now almost as low as in the US.

Comment: @Relaxed - sorry, no. The answer is "because various entrenched interests benefit from the problem, and they have more sway with US government than those wishing to fix it". It has nothing to do with complexity.

Comment: @DVK Fixing what problem now? Mexicans having too many children?

Comment: @Relaxed - having too many illegal aliens (of any origin). Whether that's due to too many children or a host of other possible causes is not really relevant; since there's a political will to NOT fix the problem in the first place since it benefits too many people with political pull and negatively affects only the people without it.

Comment: @DVK But that's the premise of the question and precisely what my comment is about! Realizing that Mexicans having too many children is not the source of the problem is not only relevant, it's crucial to even begin to understand the issue. The fact that illegal immigration has a lot more to do with entrenched interests (among other things) than this simplistic explanation would imply is part of the complexity I am referring to.

Comment: I was actually talking about Mexican illegal immigrants not about illegal immigrants with other nationalities. Even though I realize that it's not just Mexicans.

Comment: @Relaxed - I guess we look at it from a different angle. My point is that - regardless of whether this is an issue that is the first that should be tackled if you want to fix illegal immigration problem, or not, is 100% irrelevant since the larger problem isn't going to get fixed. You're operating (in your comment) under NO constraint that "this won't get fixed anyway so what does it matter"

Comment: I find this interesting because I believed that if the US really wanted to stop illegal immigration of Mexicans I'd have seen at least one news about Americans helping to combat whatever the problem is in Mexico that leads citizens to leave it.

Comment: @DVK Well, if that's 100% irrelevant, why ask, answer or even comment on a question exclusively *premised on* this being the key determinant of illegal immigration. What I am saying is the answer to the question, as asked, is: It's more complicated. If you don't think the question is interesting, don't take it out on me for pointing this out! (I don't even understand what the last sentence of your last comment is supposed to mean, incidentally.)

Comment: @Relaxed - I commented because I find the question's premise (as well as proposed answer premise in your comments) being wrong :)

Comment: @DVK What “answer premise"? And to what question? My comment certainly was not an answer to some other question that wasn't asked. In particular, I wasn't trying to explain why some people are illegal immigrants. The answer to that particular question is quite straightforward actually: It's because the law say they are and it's entirely within a country's power to change that. Of course, it won't happen (entrenched interests and all that) but there is nothing particularly complex about that.

Comment: I'd say it's extremely complex since there are a lot of reasons why such laws exist. Such as: why would a community with individuals that are culturally and genetically more related need to accept and invest in an outsider just because he's physically in that community. These laws don't exist just because of interests of powerful people, far from that...

Comment: @CGCampbell I wasn't talking about unilaterally inforcing a change, you are... The problem begins inside the borders of Mexico... Somehow people want to leave their families to persue a better life in the US. If the US wants to stop illegal immigration from Mexico in the long-term, it needs to work with the Mexican government to tackle whatever the issues are in Mexico that make people want to live it for the US. I guess more opportunities and better living standards would do the trick or give money to Mexico to monitor the borders too.. something along these lines...

Comment: I said almight USA because it's quite an internationally known fact that when the US wants something it gets it.. The US didn't need much permission to invade other countries or in the past to help overthrowing regimes and support the ones that came afterwards... But when it comes to this problem of illegal immigration, the "almight USA" seem to struggle to solve the issue.. If the immigration problem was really something the government wanted to solve, it'd have been working in Mexico a long time already with or without the consent of the Mexican government

Comment: I changed my question a little bit because it was a bit offensive when it comes when I said that poor Mexicans have children carelessly. I'm Portuguese-Brazilian and the poor part of the Brazilian population does have a much higher birth rate. When looking at the immigration problem between Mexico and the US I also took this fact with me. I still think it's a good assumption, but it seems people understood that I was saying that Mexicans have children carelessly.

Comment: The nationality doesn't matter: poor people usually have more children and for sure the immigrants crossing the border are not rich people. Finally @CGCampbell I actually answered my own question in the comments, but I only came to the conclusion that the US government isn't interested in solving the problem after this discussion here. No question is a bad question and everybody here provided new insights to each other. I really don't like the approach of stack exchange to close questions that are not taken well by people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a huge topic and likely way too broad of a topic for a simple Q/A site. But, some potential reasons to get you started:

1. US Trade Policies have contributed to the economic problems Mexico has had. For instance, [NAFTA damaged a huge sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Free_Trade_Agreement#Impact_on_Mexican_farmers) of Mexico's agricultural economy.
2. Many of the people entering the US are escaping more than economic troubles but also drug cartels--many outside of Mexico into Latin and South America. Many would argue that this is due in no small part to US policies on drugs over the past 35 years.
3. The US economy depends on illegal immigrants--namely [migrant ag workers](http://www.voanews.com/content/us-farmers-depend-on-illegal-immigrants-100541644/162082.html) so there isn't necessarily universal will to do anything about it.

Comment: "US Trade Policies have contributed to the economic problems Mexico has had." While I won't defend the obvious corruption that is the US farm bill, NAFTA is certainly more nuanced than that. NAFTA created tons of economic opportunities for Mexico. Here are some articles to give some perspective:
http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2012/may/14/nafta-key-to-economic-social-growth-in-mexico/?page=all
http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21592612-north-americas-trade-deal-has-delivered-real-benefits-job-not-done-deeper-better

Comment: @lazarusL Broadly speaking, I agree. There's a lot of plusses *and* minuses. in the context of illegal immigration, though, NAFTA hit the rural poor pretty hard in how it disrupted the traditional ag economy in Mexico. For example, Mexico now has to import corn from the US. As ag jobs were reduced in Mexico, it's yet one more reason why some would try to come north to work here in the US ag industry.

Answer (score 1):

The honest answer would be that it isn't in their best interest for that to happen. The USA has gone as far as [conspiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoriano_Huerta#Revolution), via their Ambassador Henry Lane Wilson, with Huerta to kill Madero in the days of the revolution.  So they are not shy of intervening in Mexico, the latest has been in the form of funding to the government of Mexico's Drug War via the [Mérida Initiative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9rida_Initiative).

Comment: Without specific evidence these kinds of explanations are tautological. Everything a person/country does is in their own interest - with the evidence being that they did it (or that we can retroactively identify *some* interest that was served).

Comment: https://www.ers.usda.gov/amber-waves/2012-june/immigration-policy.aspx#.U1TfkfldUSt

http://www.cbo.gov/sites/default/files/cbofiles/ftpdocs/87xx/doc8711/12-6-immigration.pdf

Basically illegal immigration has contributed to the USA economy growth. Allowing for cheaper wages and more labor force to meet the markets demand. It is not hard to see under such circumstances why the USA would not want to end illegal immigration.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you say

> I find this interesting because I believed that if the US really wanted to stop illegal immigration of Mexicans I'd have seen at least one news about Americans helping to combat whatever the problem is in Mexico that leads citizens to leave it.

I've seen such news shows.

1. The United States in Mexico, [supporting Mexican police against the drug cartels](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/28039287/ns/world_news-americas/t/us-gives-mexico-million-battle-cartels/).
2. The United States and Mexico signing [NAFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Free_Trade_Agreement), to increase employment opportunities in Mexico.
3. The United States helping Mexico [secure its Southern border](http://www.foxnews.com/us/2017/02/02/mexican-us-military-officials-discuss-iniatives-to-protect-mexicos-southern-border.html) to prevent immigration by people trying to travel through Mexico.

> There will be illegal immigrants as long as poor Mexicans keep having children carelessly and as long as there are no opportunities for them in Mexico.

Is that the primary problem?  Some believe that a border wall is necessary not to prevent people looking for opportunity, who are better targeted with systems like [E-Verify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Verify), but to prevent reentry by criminals.  Currently, drug traffickers and gang members can cross the border with relative ease.  Even after being deported, they repeatedly return.

The US and Mexico have a closed border that can only be crossed legally at restricted points that require ID checks.  But enforcement of that border still does not prevent people illegally in the US after multiple deportations from [committing crimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Kathryn_Steinle).

Enforcing the border is a necessary part of law enforcement.  Sticking our heads in the sand won't change that.  The US has been waging war on poverty for fifty years.  Hundreds of billions of dollars later, we have as much poverty now as when we started.  Such programs won't magically work in Mexico where they failed in the US.

Another issue is that there are certain jobs that require transient labor to perform.  Primarily related to crop harvesting, these would ideally take advantage of laborers from Mexico resting between the planting and harvesting cycles there.  But under the current system, such temporary workers have too much trouble getting visas.  So they cross the border illegally.  And then they stay, because it is difficult to cross the border twice (leaving and then coming back next year).

Nothing that the US could do in Mexico would change that.  That would have to be changed either by easier temporary visas or by finding domestic sources of labor (e.g. the inner cities, which often have high unemployment).  Currently most city residents aren't interested in such jobs.  And temporary visas are too difficult to get.  There's too much paperwork and approval is too spotty.  Illegal immigrants require no paperwork or approval, just cash.